# Woocommerce Product Export : add multiple meta fields using function add_export_data( $value, $product )

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Wordpress Site : Woocommerce Plugin**

I have multiple meta product fields that I need to export.

I have looked up the reference in [WooCommerce Product CSV Importer & Exporter Documentation](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Importer-&-Exporter#adding-custom-export-columns-developers) but I am having a little trouble understanding how to expand the example to add more than one custom column.

**This part I am fine with**

$columns is an array

So all I need to do is add an array item for each custom field.

```
 /**
 * Add the custom column to the exporter and the exporter column menu.
 *
 * @param array $columns
 * @return array $columns
 */
function add_export_column( $columns ) {

    // column slug => column name
    $columns['my_custom_supplier_product_code'] = 'Supplier Product CODE';
    $columns['my_custom_supplier_product_desc'] = 'Supplier Product DESC';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_column_names', 'add_export_column' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_default_columns', 'add_export_column' );
```

**Here I am not quite sure what to do**

***REFERENCE***

```
/**
 * Provide the data to be exported for one item in the column.
 *
 * @param mixed $value (default: '')
 * @param WC_Product $product
 * @return mixed $value - Should be in a format that can be output into a text file (string, numeric, etc).
 */
function add_export_data( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'custom_column', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
// Filter you want to hook into will be: 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_{$column_slug}'.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_custom_column', 'add_export_data', 10, 2 );
```

***My mod for my first custom column***

```
/**
 * Provide the data to be exported for one item in the column.
 *
 * @param mixed $value (default: '')
 * @param WC_Product $product
 * @return mixed $value - Should be in a format that can be output into a text file (string, numeric, etc).
 */
function add_export_data( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'my_custom_supplier_product_code', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
// Filter you want to hook into will be: 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_{$column_slug}'.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_my_custom_supplier_product_code', 'add_export_data', 10, 2 );
```

Now how do I add what is required for my second column ?

Should I have

- 2 x *add_export_data functions*
- 2 x *add_filter*

```
/**
 * Provide the data to be exported for one item in CUSTOM COLUMN 1
 *
 * @param mixed $value (default: '')
 * @param WC_Product $product
 * @return mixed $value - Should be in a format that can be output into a text file (string, numeric, etc).
 */
function add_export_data_my_custom_supplier_product_code( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'my_custom_supplier_product_code', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
// Filter you want to hook into will be: 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_{$column_slug}'.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_my_custom_supplier_product_code', 'add_export_data_my_custom_supplier_product_code', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Provide the data to be exported for one item in CUSTOM COLUMN 2
 *
 * @param mixed $value (default: '')
 * @param WC_Product $product
 * @return mixed $value - Should be in a format that can be output into a text file (string, numeric, etc).
 */
function add_export_data_my_custom_supplier_product_desc( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'my_custom_supplier_product_desc', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
// Filter you want to hook into will be: 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_{$column_slug}'.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_my_custom_supplier_product_desc', 'add_export_data_my_custom_supplier_product_desc', 10, 2 );
```

Note that I have tried the code as above, but for some reason

- ALL of my columns appear in the spreadsheet
- SOME are empty and are not pulling the data from the Product Custom Fields

Rather than 'hacking around' trying to fix the issue, I am now stepping back to try to get a better understanding of how this works.

Thanks

Comment: From that documentation, it appears as if you will indeed need to add a filter function for each individual field.

Comment: Your modifications for the first column, did those work as intended? _“ALL of my columns appear in the spreadsheet”_ - “all” meaning what, default columns, custom columns, both? Based on what did you expect to see less than those? _“SOME are empty and are not pulling the data from the Product Custom Fields”_ - which ones? Anything special about those? Doe the return values you are getting from those satisfy the condition mentioned in the code comments, `Should be in a format that can be output into a text file (string, numeric, etc)`?

Comment: @CBroe I have 11 fields I need to export. The missing values did not seem to fit any pattern. Some TEXT fields exported, some did not. Some NUMBER fields exported, some did not. The odd thing is that when I select **[x] Export all Metadata** ... all the correct values appear in the corresponding Metadata fields. As per my post comment, I am stepping back and working methodically to add one-by-one and test each with an export.

Comment: Maybe start by double-checking the spellings everywhere. The name of the hooks seem to be related directly to the column slugs, so even the tiniest misspelling there will likely cause it to not call any function for the field in question.

Comment: Oh. Just to add a little more information: My custom fields were created with **ACF : Advanced Custom Fields**. I did go directly into the mysql database `post_meta_ table' and double checked the `meta_key` and `meta_value`. That all looks fine.

Comment: @CBroe : A cup of coffee first, and then I am doing that spelling check. I did do it all methodically, and checked and checked again. I used a DUMMY bit of text, and then did a search and replace with each column slug to make sure it was all pasted correctly, and not finger trouble. But yes, that is where I am starting again now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, and a suggestion that may help others.

Yes, I was correct in my code snippet above.
It does work as expected.

@CBroe was correct:

> Maybe start by double-checking the spellings everywhere. The name of
> the hooks seem to be related directly to the column slugs, so even the
> tiniest misspelling there will likely cause it to not call any
> function for the field in question.

My issues were essentially finger trouble

I have 11 Custom Fields.

That gets a little unwieldy when the custom_field_slug references get separated by other code.

So I am adding here

- a breakdown to explain what steps are needed
- and a formatting suggestion that has made life a lot easier for me to scan across a whole group of related items to make sure I haven't got any typos

**STEP 1 : Add Custom Columns to Array for Mapping**

```
/* [ mycode ] EXPORT : ADD custom columns to Exporter
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
 * Add the custom columns to the exporter and the exporter column menu.
 *
 * @param array $columns
 * @return array $columns
 *
 */
 
function add_export_columns( $columns ) {

    // ---------------------------------------------------- Company SYSTEM Fields
    // column slug                                 > column name
    $columns['company_system_item_code']           = 'Company SYSTEM Item Code';
    $columns['company_system_item_description']    = 'Company SYSTEM Item Description';
    $columns['company_system_item_category']       = 'Company SYSTEM Item Category';
    $columns['company_system_item_unit_weight']    = 'Company SYSTEM Item Unit Weight';
    $columns['company_system_item_unit_price']     = 'Company SYSTEM Item Unit Price';

    // ---------------------------------------------------- Company WEBSITE Fields
    // column slug                                 > column name
    $columns['company_website_discount_percent']   = 'Company WEBSITE Discount Percent';
    $columns['company_website_item_unit_price']    = 'Company WEBSITE Item Unit Price';
    $columns['company_website_item_minimum_units'] = 'Company WEBSITE Item Minimum Units';
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------- Company SUPPLIER Fields
    // column slug                                 > column name
    $columns['company_supplier_item_code']         = 'Company_SUPPLIER Item Code';
    $columns['company_supplier_item_description']  = 'Company SUPPLIER Item Description';
    $columns['company_supplier_item_unit_price']   = 'Company SUPPLIER Item Unit Price';
    
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_column_names', 'add_export_columns' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_default_columns', 'add_export_columns' );
```

**STEP 2 : All the Export Data Functions**

```
/* [ mycode ] EXPORT : GET data to be exported
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
 *
 * Functions to provide the data to be exported for one item in EACH column.
 *
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------- Company SYSTEM Fields
function add_export_data_company_system_item_code( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_system_item_code', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
function add_export_data_company_system_item_description( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_system_item_description', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
function add_export_data_company_system_item_category( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_system_item_category', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
function add_export_data_company_system_item_unit_weight( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_system_item_unit_weight', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
function add_export_data_company_system_item_unit_price( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_system_item_unit_price', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------- Company WEBSITE Fields
function add_export_data_company_website_discount_percent( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_website_discount_percent', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
function add_export_data_company_website_item_unit_price( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_website_item_unit_price', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
function add_export_data_company_website_item_minimum_units( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_website_item_minimum_units', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------- Company SUPPLIER Fields
function add_export_data_company_supplier_item_code( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_supplier_item_code', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
function add_export_data_company_supplier_item_description( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_supplier_item_description', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
function add_export_data_company_supplier_item_unit_price( $value, $product ) {
    $value = $product->get_meta( 'company_supplier_item_unit_price', true, 'edit' );
    return $value;
}
```

**STEP 3 : All the Filters**

```
/**
 *
 * Add filters to hook in for EACH column
 *
 */
 
// ------------------------------------------------------- Company SYSTEM Fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_system_item_code'         , 'add_export_data_company_system_item_code', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_system_item_description'  , 'add_export_data_company_system_item_description', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_system_item_category'     , 'add_export_data_company_system_item_category', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_system_item_unit_weight'  , 'add_export_data_company_system_item_unit_weight', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_system_item_unit_price'   , 'add_export_data_company_system_item_unit_price', 10, 2 );

// ------------------------------------------------------- Company WEBSITE Fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_website_discount_percent'  , 'add_export_data_company_website_discount_percent', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_website_item_unit_price'   , 'add_export_data_company_website_item_unit_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_website_item_minimum_units', 'add_export_data_company_website_item_minimum_units', 10, 2 );

// ------------------------------------------------------- Company SUPPLIER Fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_supplier_item_code'        , 'add_export_data_company_supplier_item_code', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_supplier_item_description' , 'add_export_data_company_supplier_item_description', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_company_supplier_item_unit_price'  , 'add_export_data_company_supplier_item_unit_price', 10, 2 );
```

NOTE also the white space padding I used to align the components.

When you have many column slugs of different length, it's quite awkward to scan for errors.

If you don't have *every* hook and *every* function named correctly with the appropriate column slugs, then you won't get the expected results.

---

Hopefully this worked example may be useful for someone else in future.